# Setting User Agent field or Get Parameters in S3 Lib for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

we're trying to set some HTTP fields for an iOS application's S3 requests. We're trying to have this data when we read from the S3 log bucket we have set up. We're trying to differentiate between different clients and different versions accessing our S3 bucket. We tried some code but the results we want just aren't showing in the log bucket.

Either being able to set the User-Agent field or being able to put additional GET parameters in the request would be useful to us. According to the [S3 Log documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?LogFormat.html), "Amazon S3 will ignore query-string parameters that begin with "x-", but will include those parameters in the access log record for the request, as part of the Request-URI field of the log record." We tried that with the following code, but it seemed like the library was disregarding the data:

```
S3GetObjectRequest* s3request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:pdfInfo.s3Path
                                                            withBucket:[Authenticate sharedInstance].bucket];

NSString* urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?X-App-Version=%@;X-App-Client=iOS", s3request.urlRequest.URL.absoluteURL, kAppVersion];
s3request.urlRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];

[s3request.urlRequest setValue:kAppVersion forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-App-Version"];
[s3request.urlRequest setValue:@"iOS" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-App-Client"];
[s3request.urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"App-IOS/%@ Alpha", kAppVersion] forHTTPHeaderField:@"USER_AGENT"];
```

Then we tried setting the User Agent field, like this:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:[Authenticate sharedInstance].accessKey
     withSecretKey:[Authenticate sharedInstance].secretKey];

s3.userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ X-App-Version %@", s3.userAgent, kAppVersion];
```

We couldn't see the data showing up in the logs. Does anybody have any experience doing either of these? Thanks.